# SQL: select the last values before a space in a string

Tags: sql

I have a set of strings like this:

```
CAP BCP0018 36
MFP ACZZ1BD 265
LZP FEI-12 3
```

I need to extract only the last values from the right and before the space, like:

```
36
265
3
```

how will the select statement look like? I tried using the below statement, but it did not work.

```
select CHARINDEX(myField, ' ', -1)
FROM myTable;
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest method in SQL Server is:

```
select t.*, v.value
from t cross apply
     (select top (1) value
      from string_split(t.col, ' ') 
      where t.col like concat('% ', val)
     ) v;
```

This is perhaps not the most performant method.  You probably would use:

```
select right(t.col, charindex(' ', reverse(t.col)) - 1)
```

Note:  If there are no spaces, then to prevent an error:

```
select right(t.col, charindex(' ', reverse(t.col) + ' ') - 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have mentioned **CHARINDEX()** in question, I am assuming you are using SQL Server.
Try below

```
declare @table table(col varchar(100))
insert into @table values('CAP BCP0018 36')
insert into @table values('MFP ACZZ1BD 265')
insert into @table values('LZP FE-12 3')

SELECT REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(col),CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(col)) - 1)) FROM @table
```

Functions used

[CHARINDEX ( expressionToFind , expressionToSearch  )](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)  : returns position of FIRST occurence of an expression inside another expression.

[LEFT ( character_expression , integer_expression )](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/left-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)  : Returns the left part of a character string with the specified number of characters.

[REVERSE ( string_expression )](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/reverse-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)  : Returns the reverse order of a string value